# Assistance Needed with Ubuntu 23.10 Internal Clock Issue

Tags: boot, 23.10

During boot-up, I'm seeing an error message stating "internal clock never stabilized." This message is followed by a brief delay of 2 to 3 seconds before the system proceeds to boot normally.

Despite attempting some troubleshooting by syncing the hardware clock, the problem persists.

[image: Problem:Internal Clock Never Stabilised]
[image: troubleshooting]

Comment: Are you using or do you need to use a SD card?

Comment: no i do not want to use sd card

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Charlotte, NC, USA!

I was getting the same error.  **Removing the micro SD card adapter from the SD card port fixed the issue for me.**

For reference, the micro SD card adapter did not contain a micro SD card.  I have not tried restarting with a micro SD card loaded into the micro SD adapter.